# Restrict text box to two decimal places in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to restrict a text box to two decimal places using JavaScript. The field also cannot start with a Period.

```
jQuery.fn.ForceCurrencyOnly = function () {
return this.each(function () {
    $(this).keypress(function () {

        //Only allow period and numbers
        if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        //Prevent a period being entered first
        else if (event.which == 46 && $(this).val().length == 0) {
           event.preventDefault();
        }

        //Only two numbers after a decimal
        else if (($(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && ($(this).val().substring($(this).val().indexOf('.'), $(this).val().indexOf('.').length).length > 2)) {
           event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

};

The above restricts the input to numbers, a single period and a maximum of two decimal places. My problem is once 100.00 is entered, the value cannot be highlighted and removed with a number. It has to be deleted.

Is there a simpler way of only allowing a currency with two decimal places?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Edited my answer. It should work if you are using html5.

Answer (score 3):

### Try this:

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/8JEF9/

---

***HTML:***

```
Number: <input type="text" id="txt" />
```

***jQuery:***

Create a **jQuery** `function` to always get a `number` in the expected format:

```
jQuery.fn.getNum = function() {

    /* trim the string value */
    var val = $.trim($(this).val());

    /* replace all ',' to '.' if present */
    if(val.indexOf(',') > -1) {
        val = val.replace(',', '.');
    }

    /* parse the string as float */
    var num = parseFloat(val);

    /* use two decimals for the number */
    var num = num.toFixed(2);

    /* check if 'num' is 'NaN', this will happen 
     * when using characters, two '.' and apply 
     * for other cases too.
     */ 
    if(isNaN(num)) {
        num = '';
    }

    return num;
}
```

Then, force the `textbox` to have the expected `value` using `.blur(..)`

```
$(function() { //onReady handler for document

    $('#txt').blur(function() { //onBlur handler for textbox
        $(this).val($(this).getNum()); //invoke your function, you can use it with other selectors too
    });

});
```

Just to know, if you put something like ***20.129***, your textbox value will be ***20.13*** *(this means that the value will be rounded).*

I've tested many possible situations and works fine, maybe you can customize the `function` as you wish for other purposes.

Comment: if check the js fiddle link and saw it is taking alpha too?

Comment: @Thomas can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

How about applying a RegEx validation :

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}$" />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just check if entered key is not backspace in final check

```
jQuery.fn.ForceCurrencyOnly = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).keypress(function(event) {


             console.log(event.which);
             //Only allow period and numbers
             //Only allow period and numbers
             if (event.which != 8 && (event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
             event.preventDefault();
             }

             //Prevent a period being entered first
             else if (event.which == 46 && $(this).val().length == 0) {
             event.preventDefault();
             }

             //Only two numbers after a decimal
             else if ( event.which != 8 && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) && ($(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && ($(this).val().substring($(this).val().indexOf('.'), $(this).val().indexOf('.').length).length > 2)) {
             event.preventDefault();
             }

        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Pressing delete works fine and deletes the input. I want to be able to delete the input by highlighting 100.00 and entering 1 for example. This is how I normally clear fields.

Comment: @ministrymason updated the code to check when input is highlighted and a digit key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
jQuery.fn.getNum = function() {
var val = $.trim($(this).val());
if(val.indexOf(',') > -1) {
    val = val.replace(',', '.');
}
var num = parseFloat(val);
var num = num.toFixed(1);
if(isNaN(num)) {
    num = '';
}
return num;
}

$(function() {

$('#txt').keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).getNum());
});

});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#YourtxtId").keypress(function () {
var txt = $("#YourtxtId").val();
if (txt.indexOf(".") > -1 && txt.split(".")[1].length > 1) {
var substr = txt.split(".")[1].substring(0, 1);
$("#YourtxtId").val(txt.split(".")[0] + "." + substr);
}
```